# Create an email from data in MongoDB using Python

Tags: python, mongodb, email, django-templates, mustache

I have some data in mongodb and would like to create an email which pulls data from the db and inserts it into some sort of (mustache/django'esque) email template and then sends it.

The data has been scraped from a website with articles and when new articles are retrieved I'd like to create a summary email of all the new articles from this particular site.

So far I've discovered [premailer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/premailer/) which looks like it will be useful for the necessary inline css. [python-emails](https://github.com/lavr/python-emails) looks somewhat promising as well...

Surely it is a common task to create well formatted emails from data in a db using python? But surprisingly I haven't been able to find any specific information about how to do this.

EDIT: I just discovered [this](https://github.com/bendavis78/django-template-email) way of using django to generate emails from their templates. I'll investigate this further and update my question here once I find a functioning solution.

Comment: Did you write some or you are asking how to start?

Comment: @WalidSaad I'm not completely sure how to start although I just found a way of using Django to create email templates. I'll update my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need Django, you can use a templating engine like [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/) to create the email templates and inject data into them, then use smtplib to send the email.

Comment: I just looked into it and I reckon that you are right and that's the way to go. I will use Jinja2 to create the template, premailer to convert all the css into inline and pymongo (of course) to pull the data from the db and inject into the template engine.